# Images going crazy after using two setTimeout functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a pong game using html/css/javascript and all went well until I added a second setTimeout()

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="player.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="ball.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="funcs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cetrnes.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="universe-54a.jpg" width="700px" height="525px" onclick="back()"></img>
    <img id="player" src="player1.png" onload="move()"></img>
    <img id="ball" src="ball.png"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

The css is irrelevant.

The player.js script:

```
function Player(ID) {
    this.t;
    this.y = 170;
    this.speed = -3;
    this.move = function move() {
        if (this.y > 1 && this.y < 421) {
            this.y += this.speed;
        }
        else if (this.y < 1) {
            this.y = 2;
            this.speed = 3;
        }
        else {
            this.y = 420;
            this.speed = -3;
        }
        document.getElementById(ID).style.top=this.y + "px";
        this.t = setTimeout("this.move()",10);
    }
    this.back = function back() {
        if (this.speed < 0) 
            this.speed = 3;
        else
            this.speed = -3;
    }
}

var player = new Player("player");
```

The ball.js script:

```
function Ball(ID) {
    this.t;
    this.x = 350;
    this.y = 260;
    this.left = true;
    this.bot = true;
    this.acc = 5;
    this.move = function move() {
        if (this.bot)
            this.y -= 3;
        else if (!this.bot)
            this.y += 3;
        if (this.left)
            this.x -= 3;
        else if (!this.left)
            this.x += 3;
        document.getElementById(ID).style.top = this.y + "px";
        document.getElementById(ID).style.left = this.x + "px";
        this.t = setTimeout("this.move()",10);
    }
}

var ball = new Ball("ball");
```

And the funcs.js script:

```
function move() {
    player.move();
    ball.move();
}

function back() {
    player.back();
}
```

The move function in player.js makes the player move up and down, and the back function makes it change its direction. It works fine when I only call that. The move function in ball.js makes the ball move. It works fine when I only call that. But when I call them both the player goes crazy and goes up and down very fast, while the ball just flies out of the screen. My coding may look a bit odd, but I had certain other problems while writing and this way of writing works.

I would appreciate help, thank you.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k0mnphL9/6/ if you comment the either ball.move() or player.move() on lines 51 and 52 it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pause the script execution in the console and hover over `this.move` used in the `Ball` or `Player` function, you'll see that `this.move` is referring to:

```
function move() {
    player.move();
    ball.move();
}
```

which means that for every time `this.move` gets called inside of the `Player` or `Ball`, it gets called another two times in `player.move()` and in `ball.move()`.

Comment: This helped me find a solution, I removed the setTimeout from both Ball and Player classes and added it to the function move(), but I don't fully understand how was I invoking then two times.

Comment: I didn't add this to the answer because I was not certain, but I think it may have to do with calling `this.move` inside of `move`, which meant that the global `move` was used because the local one wasn't finished being declared into `this.move`